# Elasticsearch index backup options

Tags: search, elasticsearch, indexing

how to perform the index backup and recover ES in same or different servers if any failure in the network or disk read. we gone through snapshot option is there any other options available to implement it and we need to perform backup on weekly and daily basis,kinldy help us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my company, we use a [crontab](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) that runs a shell scripting (using `curl`) every night using [Snapshot API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/backing-up-your-cluster.html). Note that you can restore your backup on another cluster, even if this cluster have a [posterior version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) of ES.

All files go to Amazon S3 through the [Cloud AWS Plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws)

- To create the `crontab` runs at terminal:

`crontab -e`

- With `vi` or `nano`, add this line at the end, supposing that you want that this runs every day at 5am:

`5 0 * * * /home/shell_scripts_directory/snapshot.sh`

Then create `snapshot` shell script the on the location specified above:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
S3_REPO="s3"
NODE_IP="192.168.1.80"
COMMAND="http://${NODE_IP}:9200/_snapshot/${S3_REPO}/${NOW}"

RESULT=$(curl -s -XPUT "$COMMAND")
echo "Snapshot from [$NOW] at [$S3_REPO] resulted with $RESULT" >> /tmp/snapshot.log
```

Note that this script also creates a log `/tmp/snapshot.log`

To get information about *current snapshot* tasks:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/_status"
```

You also can see specific tasks using the label of your backup, even if it's not currently running:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_status"
```

Comment: how to use crontab with curl command can you please post your sample example as well

Comment: How to identify the time taken for snapshot completion? and Will the snapshot impacts the search performance ?

Comment: @user3351014 Snapshots tasks do not execute queries to retrieve data, thus the impact on search is not considerable. More information about the snapshot task added above.

Comment: if i  have 6-7 nodes, when  doing snapshot in filesystem  which node will save the snapshots ? if i have huge data how to run parallel with multiple threads to take the snapshot